# Password protecting zipped directories in bash

Tags: zip

When I use the -P option to zip files like this:

```
zip -P password filename.zip filename
```

It properly asks me for the password when I attempt to unzip it but when I attempt to do the same for difectories like this:

```
zip -r -P password archivename.zip directoryname
```

It for some reason doesn't ask for a password when I try to unzip it. Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: since you pass the password as parameter, isn't normal that it doesn't ask you for a password?

Comment: @vdavid Certainly it doesn't (and shouldn't) ask for a password when I am zipping the directory however the issue is that it also doesn't ask for a password when I am trying to unzip the file.

Comment: Works fine here with Info-ZIP zip 3.0 and unzip 6.0.